# Regular Expressions in Java replace odd # of slashes

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression that will replace odd number of slashes with even number of slashes while leave the even number of slashes intact. 

**For Example:**

- Test/123 --> Test//123
- Test//123 --> Test//123
- Test///123 --> Test//////123

Comment: I just need help with writing the regular expression. something like: [/]{odd} with [//]{odd}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!/)/(//)*(?!/)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
  String outputStr = m.replaceAll("$0$0");
```

- `(?<!/)` makes sure there are no slashes right before the match;
- `/(//)*` matches an odd number of slashes;
- `(?!/)` makes sure there are no slashes right after the match.

The replacement string is `$0$0`, which doubles up the matched slashes.

I've tested this on your inputs, and it works exactly as per your spec.

Comment: Consider using negative lookahead/lookbehing as in my reply. Easier than using positive expressions and manually negating them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(?<!/)((//)*/)(?!/)` with whatever you want instead.

Comment: The problem is replacing it with an even number of // depending on captured string. This regex as I tried captures any even number of /

Comment: Any odd number. You can easily replace it with just twice that many slashes, or n+1.